# Quantization of string theories and gerbes

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory

The explanation of the photoelectric effect by Einstein and the structure of Maxwell equations have lead De Broglie to assert that matter has a dual nature: Often it may show particles and wave properties. This concept it emphasized with string theory which replaces a particle by a string.

The state  phase of a quantum system is defined by a projective bundle $P(E)\rightarrow M$ whose typical fibre is a the projective space $P({\cal H})$ associated to the Hilbert space ${\cal H}$. The obstruction to define the phase space: that is an ${\cal H}$-bundle $E\rightarrow M$ whose associated projective bundle is $P(E)$ is defined by a $U(1)$-gerbe on $M$. We can relate this with the following geometric uncertainty: a phase is defined up to an element of $U(1)$, which in the language of descent theory corresponds to the fact that the phase space is determined locally up to an isomorphism.

The Berry phase of a phase space of a quantum system whose group of symmetry is $U(1)$ in an adiabatic evolution is defined by the holonomy of a connection of a $U(1)$-bundle. With  this uncertainty,  one cannot describe the Berry phase, but an error induced which corresponds to the holonomy of a gerbe which describes the evolution of a string. Henceforth, the error induced by the uncertainty implies that we cannot describe a particle precisely, but a string which contains  a particle. This may give a conceptual explanation of the wave properties of the matter, as the wave properties appear when it is not possible to measure precisely physical data  expressed here by a sheaf of categories and not a bundle. This emphasizes the fact that the nature of the matter is corpuscular, and its wave properties that are observed are a consequence of uncertainty.

We call the process which enables to define a string theory as the error determined by an uncertainty for a theory of particle a quantization.

Question:  What are the examples of string theory  which are defined from a theory of particle by such a quantization ?

https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.10254

Comment: Asked and answered - this appears to be a simple advertisement for a paper. Without judging the possible mathematical merit of the construction, there is no physics case for attempting it. Conceptually, quantum field theory adequately represents the quantum nature of particles. Experimentally, quantum phenomena are readily accessible and there is no evidence that the wave nature observed in the position representation has anything to do with waves on a one-dimensional string.

Comment: There is a question at the end of this post, if you know an example of a quantum theory constructed from a particle theory, I will be glad to know it.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the final passages of your post - it sounded to me like you were answering your question yourself by giving the arXiv reference. Certainly, in the early days of quantum mechanics, one started out with the notion of a particle and one devised a mathematical framework for "quantizing" its motion - I don't know whether that's what you mean by "constructing a quantum theory from a particle theory". For a large class of phenomena, this is still adequate, and there is no evidence of any stringy character. But fundamentally, we now view particles as quantized excitations ...

Comment: ... of a field, and I know of no fully consistent description that starts out with a "particle" as a fundamental object.

Comment: I was not answering my question. I am pointing out and example of a process that I call quantization from a particle theory (which is the example developed in the paper), and I want to know if there exists others examples like so, or some known examples of quantum field theory can be described by this mathematical procedure.

Comment: I misunderstood you then, sorry. I personally don't know of other examples of this procedure of quantization.